# Why does my Dask client show zero workers, cores, and memory?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dask

I'm using Dask deployed using Helm on a Kubernetes cluster in Kubernetes Engine on GCP. My current cluster set up has 5 nodes with each node having 8 cpus, 30 gb:

I ran the notebook named `05-nyc-taxi.ipynb`, which resulted in workers getting killed.

When I restarted the Dask client it shows that I now have zero workers and zero memory:

[image]

However, when I run `kubectl get services` and `kubectl get pods`, it shows that my pods and services are running:

[image]

Any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

When you restart the client, is kills all the workers, and starts making new ones. That process is asynchronous, but the rendering of the client object happens immediately - so there are no workers at that moment. You could render the client object again (and again) later:

```
In[]:  client
```

Or check the dashboard.

Or, better, you could render the cluster object itself which, so long as you have jupyter widgets installed in the environment, will update itself in real-time. If you didn't happen to assign your cluster object before, it will also be available as `client.cluster`.

btw: *why* are you having to restart the cluster like this?

Comment: Thanks @mdurant. Whenever something I cannot explain happens, I restart the kernel followed by `client.restart()` to clear the memory. Most of the time it works, but occasionally it doesnt and your explanation here helps a ton for this specific situation. When all attempts to recover the cluster fails, I just delete it and reinstall everything. Perhaps there is a simpler way to restart a notebook on a Kubernetes cluster. If so, suggestions are welcome.